# In Pandas Python in columns of data, fix formatting so all the data comes out formatted the same, or has a blank in its place

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, dataset

I have four columns of data, I need to create some type of formatting so that when I run the program, all of the data comes out formatted the same, or has a blank in its place.

For example my some of current code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame (

    [['Jim','Black',abc10001,'555-123-4434'],
    ['Jack','Moore',10002,'547=342=2342'],
    ['Mary','00May',10003,'-231-3424'],
    ['John','',32412,'412-232-5532']],
    index = [1,2,3,4],
    columns = ['first_name','last_name','zip_code','phone_number'])
print(df)

df.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

would print out :

```
   first_name   last_name zip_code  phone_number

1         Jim       Black    abc10001  555-123-4434

2        Jack       Moore    10002     547-342-2342

3        Mary       00May    10003        -231-3424

4        John                32412     412-232-5532
```

What I need is when is it to print out:

```
  first_name   last_name zip_code  phone_number

1         Jim       Black           555-123-4434

2        Jack       Moore    10002  547=342=2342

3        Mary                10003  

4        John                32412  412-232-5532
```

I have already used `df.fillna('', inplace=true)` for fields that have no data. But I not sure what to use now.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your zip_code line:

```
df['zip_code'] = pd.to_numeric(df.zip_code.astype(str), errors='coerce').fillna(0).replace(0.0,'')
```

This will fix you last_name line:

```
df['last_name'] =df['last_name'][df.last_name.str.match(r'^[A-Za-z]+$')] 
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

This will fix you phone_number section:

```
df['phone_number'] = df['phone_number'][df.phone_number.str.match(r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}')]
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

I matched the pattern that phone numbers and last_names should have to format the column, and removed the ones that didn't match the format. I hope this helps

```
df = pd.DataFrame (

    [['Jim','Black','abc10001','555-123-4434'],
    ['Jack','Moore',10002,'547-342-2342'],
    ['Mary','00May',10003,'-231-3424'],
    ['John','',32412,'412-232-5532']],
    index = [1,2,3,4],
    columns = ['first_name','last_name','zip_code','phone_number'])

df.fillna('', inplace=True)

df['zip_code'] = pd.to_numeric(df.zip_code.astype(str), errors='coerce').fillna(0).replace(0.0,'')

df['last_name'] =df['last_name'][df.last_name.str.match(r'^[A-Za-z]+$')] 

df['phone_number'] = df['phone_number'][df.phone_number.str.match(r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}')]
df.fillna('', inplace=True)

print(df)
#  first_name last_name zip_code  phone_number
#1        Jim     Black           555-123-4434
#2       Jack     Moore    10002  547-342-2342
#3       Mary              10003              
#4       John              32412  412-232-5532
```

Comment: Hi, this code still prints out the incorrect format rather than a blank.

Comment: Kate, can you explain in a little more detail, i'd like to fix it for you if possible, as i think i'm close?

Comment: yes,  when I run the code it still prints out                                             first_name   last_name zip_code  phone_number

1         Jim       Black    abc10001  555-123-4434

2        Jack       Moore    10002     547-342-2342

3        Mary       00May    10003        -231-3424

4        John                      32412     412-232-5532.

Comment: I just now updated it, it should get you the output at the end, that's what your looking for correct?

Comment: Actually I got it too work the error was my end. Thank you so much.